# Spyder kernel cannot start when adding another path

Tags: python, spyder

Couple of days ago, while doing a course on python I installed selenium module and chromedriver. I used them without problems for a few days and then one day all of a sudden I get an error that the selenium module cannot be found. I thought that the problem is that maybe selenium was installed in different folder and when I add another python path in Spyder and then restart it I get the error that I'm copying entirely:

An error ocurred while starting the kernel

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 23, in 
start.main()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 289, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 26, in 
from spyder_kernels.py3compat import TimeoutError, PY2, _print, encode
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 71, in 
import configparser
File "C:\Users\Windows HD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site‑packages\configparser.py", line 11, in 
from backports.configparser import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backports.configparser'
```

Generally, I have to admit that I don't entirely understand the whole thing with the paths, environmental variables and all that and I'm assuming that I've probably messed something up. So if anybody could explain to me what exactly is the problem and how to solve it and if anybody knows any particular course that is teaching these things I would be very grateful. I'm using python version 3.8 and Spyder 4.1.5 fi those are relevant information.
Thank you guys.

Comment: Have you actually got  a file path with Python39 in it (the last file path in your code before the error)? You mentioned you were using python 3.8?

Comment: I think I do, when I go to tools ---> current user environment variables, under path there are locations: 
C:\Users\Windows HD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39 and C:\Users\Windows HD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts

Comment: Post the path you added, and all the file paths. If it worked at one point, you'll need to find out what happened to your build. That's going to be (could well be) a major headache for you, and probably something you won't get a quick fix to here, as it's hard to diagnose through chat. Also find the file 'configparser.py', and post the code where the error is happening: in and around line 11.

Comment: Ok in the meantime I realized that the kernel stops working when I try to add this path which is already added: 
C:\Users\Windows HD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39. 
However, when I restart Spyder and try to run the code, the kernel is working but I get error No module named 'selenium'. Now, that module is stored in this location: 
"C:\Users\Windows HD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\selenium"
and when I try to add that specific path, ending with \site-packages,  it stops working again with the same message as before.

Comment: How did you install it, did you use pip3? If so, see following steps below.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to remove the additional Python  3.9 you have in your computer and instead install selenium with pip in the Anaconda prompt.

Comment: I've installed selenium in the Anaconda prompt and now it seems to be working fine, without removing Python 3.9. so thank you for your help. I was a little reluctant to remove it because I couldn't find any other version installed even though in the Spyder console at the beginning it says it is using Python 3.8.5

Answer (score 0):

Just try installing it manually -  download the package and unpack contents to a folder:

https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ed/9c/9030520bf6ff0b4c98988448a93c04fcbd5b13cd9520074d8ed53569ccfe/selenium-3.141.0.tar.gz

Navigate to the folder you unpacked it to in your command window:

```
cd c:\folder_location\folder_name
```

And then from that location do a manual install, using the setup file contained in the build.

```
python3 setup.py install
```